# Download Google Ads - negative keyword report

Tags: google-ads-api, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to download from Google Ads - [Negative Keyword Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ZQU.png)
, using Adwords\v201809,
I found this CAMPAIGN_NEGATIVE_KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT report in Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType class
my problem is that I want to download all negative keywords includes Ad-Group level, and not only the Campaign level.
please help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about a programming problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Keyword Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywords-performance-report) with the condition `Is Negative = TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do it, but I got an empty report,
do you know if the IsNegative property is something I need to set in my google ad account, or it is done automatically?
I ran this code-
$builder = new ReportQueryBuilder();
$builder->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
)->select(['Criteria'])->where('IsNegative')->equalTo('true');
in PHP
the final query is - SELECT Criteria FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE IsNegative = true;
any idea why the report came empty?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the header: includeZeroImpressions = true
and I got the report :)